# Why is my null check not working in this IF statement in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, if-statement, null, case, varchar2

This should be a simple question.  I want a particular column claimedby to alternate between a user ID and nothing. So, I'm writing a simple procedure that should look at the column to see if a user ID is in there.  If it is, set it to nothing.  If it is nothing, then set it to the user ID.  That's all I need.  But, I'm running into difficulties with determining if the column is nothing.  I'm trying various ways, such as 1) case claimedby when null, 2) case claimedby when '', 3) if length(claimedby) < 1.  In none of the cases is the column being set to the incoming parameter userID.  It's always remaining null.  Here's my code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE claimprocedure
   ( userID IN varchar2, docketnum IN varchar2 )
IS
   claimed_by varchar2(10);

  cursor c1 is
    SELECT claimedby FROM DR_RULE24.CISR_INTAKE_ERRORS_MASTER 
     WHERE docket_num = docketnum;
     
BEGIN

  open c1;
  fetch c1 into claimed_by;
  close c1;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('claimed_by = ' || claimed_by);

CASE claimed_by
    when null then update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = userID where docket_num = docketnum;
    when '' then update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = userID where docket_num = docketnum;
    ELSE update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = '' where docket_num = docketnum;
  END CASE;
  
  if length(claimed_by) < 1 then update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = userID where docket_num = docketnum;
    else update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = '' where docket_num = docketnum;
   end if;

  if claimed_by = '' then update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = userID where docket_num = docketnum;
  else update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = '' where docket_num = docketnum;
 end if;

if claimed_by is null then update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = userID where docket_num = docketnum;
  else update DR_RULE24.cisr_intake_errors_master set claimedby = '' where docket_num = docketnum;
 end if;
   
END;
```

I confirm the column is set to null, then I call it with:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
call claimprocedure('shone','106712');
```

The column for docket number 106712 is not being set to 'shone'.  I've confirmed that the claimed_by variable in the procedure matches the structure of the claimedby column, which is varchar2(10);

I thought that maybe the IF statements might be canceling each other out.  So, I commented out all the ELSE clauses and tried again.  It's still null, proving that none of these IF statements are working.

It must be something simple.  What am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: In addition to my answer, try this: **select length(null) from dual;** If you don’t understand the output find the documentation for **length**. Then think about the condition **null < 1**; when is that ever **true**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` statement (and its cousin the `case` expression) comes in two forms: the "simple" form and the "searched" form.

The simple form looks like `case <expr> when <val1> then ... when <val2> then ... else ... end` - this is simple, easy to read, but it only works for direct equality checks. The searched form looks like `case when <condition1> then ... when <condition2> then ... else ... end`. Here you write a bit more code, but this form is much more general.

Now to your question. You are using the simple form. Its meaning is equivalent to `case when claimed_by = null then .....`  Can you spot the trouble here? If you can't, read again about `null`, and when something (**anything**) is ever **equal** to `null`.

You must use the searched form, and write your condition in the correct, SQL way: `case when claimed_by IS null then ....`

Comment: Fantastic, mathguy!  That worked perfectly.  I spent four hours yesterday searching Oracle docs, and couldn't get it to work.  Thank you for finding the little thing I was missing.  You are a great Sherlock Holmes!  8-D